# Retraction of $D^2$ implies fixed point

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $D^2 = \{ (x, y) \in \mathbb{R} : x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. 
How can I prove that if there is a retraction $r: D^2 \rightarrow X \subset D^2$, so all continuous functions $f: X \rightarrow X$ admits at least one fixed point?

Comment: Read this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2486891/find-fixed-point-domain-in-mathbbrn-other-than-dn/2487429 The hard part is to prove that $D^2$ has FPP (which is the Brouwer's Fixed Point Theorem).

Comment: @freakish I don't know if I can use it.

Comment: It is **extremely** unlikely that you will be able to prove the theorem yourself (unless you are familiar with higher-level maths, e.g. homology). And since $D^2$ is a retract of itself then the statement you are to prove would imply it. Read this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: @freakish ok, thanks for helping.

Comment: I don't understand the question grammatically.  On one reading, let $X=\{(0,0)\}$, let $r:D^2\to X$ be the retraction collapsing all of $D^2$ to the point, and then every continuous $f:X\to X$ admits at least one fixed point.

Comment: @freakish As you said, I have to use the theorem to prove it.